# Определить количество чисел кратных 4

Tags: java

Напишите программу, которая в последовательности натуральных чисел определяет количество чисел, кратных 4. Программа получает на вход количество чисел в последовательности, а затем сами числа. В последовательности всегда имеется число, кратное 4.Введённые числа не пре­вы­ша­ют 30 000. Программа должна вывести одно число — количество чисел, кратных 4.
Вот мой код

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Main{
    public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c = scanner.nextInt();
    while(c<30000) {
        if((c%4==0) && (c!=0)){
        }
    }
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Здесь могут ответить на конкретные вопросы, и могут вам помочь решить задачу, но только в том случае, если вы сами предприняли какие-то усилия. Домашние задания за автора тут не решают. Читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @МегаМозг Этот алгоритм называется циклом.:)

Comment: Молодой человек, Вы когда код пишите, Вы хотя бы пытайтесь думать, что Вы пишете. Вот у Вас переменная `c`: каков ее смысл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код в вопросе не соответстует решению задачи, он в бесконечном цикле будет выводить первое введённое число.

Это условие будет удалено при компиляции, так как в нём нет смысла.

```
    if((c%4==0) && (c!=0)){
    }
```

В задаче сказано, что сначала вводится количество чисел, которые будут введены, которые нужно проверить на кратность.
Число `30 000` нужно для определения типа чисел. В данном случае можно использовать `short`, так как максимальное его значение = `32 767`.

Ниже код решения вашей задачи.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = scanner.nextInt();
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            int number = scanner.nextShort();
            if((number % 4 == 0) && (number != 0)){
                result++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо,как вариант,но я уже сам нашел решение попроще
    import java.util.Scanner;
     class OGE7sc {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            int c = 0;
            for(int k = 1;k<=n;k++){
                System.out.println();
                c += scanner.nextInt() % 4 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                }
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int count = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        int multiplesOf4 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] % 4 == 0) {
                multiplesOf4++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(multiplesOf4);
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]